# How to correctly and safely implement C++ arithmetic operators for std::array?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17

I am looking for a correct and safe implementation of C++(17) arithmetic operators for std::array with minimal overhead.

In a first attempt, I tried to achieve the above by implementing such operators as non-member functions and by restricting the arguments taken by the operators to arrays with identical arithmetic value_types and of the same size. Two examples are given below.

```
template< typename T1, std::size_t N1, typename T2, std::size_t N2 >
constexpr inline auto operator-( const std::array< T1, N1 >& lhs, const std::array< T2, N2 >& rhs )
{
  static_assert( std::is_same< T1, T2 >::value );
  static_assert( std::is_arithmetic< T1 >::value );
  static_assert( N1 == N2 );

  std::array< T1, N1 > result;

  for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i )
  {
    result[ i ] = lhs[ i ] - rhs[ i ];
  }

  return result;
}

template< typename T1, std::size_t N1, typename T2, std::size_t N2 >
constexpr inline auto& operator-=( std::array< T1, N1 >& lhs, const std::array< T2, N2 >& rhs )
{
  static_assert( std::is_same< T1, T2 >::value );
  static_assert( std::is_arithmetic< T1 >::value );
  static_assert( N1 == N2 );

  for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i )
  {
    lhs[ i ] -= rhs[ i ];
  }

  return lhs;
}
```

I would appreciate suggestions to improve the above attempts. Especially, I am wondering if the restrictions on the arguments are correct and in case of the minus-operator maybe even too strict? Furthermore, I am asking for advice if there is any way to improve the efficiency of the implementations? That is, is there a better way to conduct the actual arithmetic operations than by the for loops given above?

Comment: Adding operators for standard containers can be problematic because argument dependent lookup may not find your operators, but only what's available in the `std` namespace (which you're not allowed to add your operators to)

Comment: instead of `static_assert( N1 == N2 );` you can just have one `size_t N` template parameter and use that as the size for both arrays.  Same goes for `T1` and `T2`.  Just make a `T` and use that for both arrays.

Comment: Read about `std::transform`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking critique of working should be asked on our sister site [codereview.se].

Comment: Caveat: if you don't know whether the code works as intended, it's not ready for [codereview.se]. Test it, make the necessary changes, *then* put it up for review. Untested code that isn't known to work as intended, will be closed as off-topic on CR.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, adding non-member operators to a type should be done in the namespace of the type.  Without doing that, your operators won't be found via ADL, and that leads to constant pain.

It is not legal to add non-member operators into `namespace std`.

So the punchline is, don't do this.

Instead, try this:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct vecarray : std::array<T,N> {
  static_assert( std::is_arithmetic< T >::value );
  using std::array<T,N>::array;
  vecarray& operator+=( std::array<T,N> const& rhs )& {
    for (auto& x:*this) {
      x += rhs[ std::addressof(x)- this->data() ];
    }
    return *this;
  }
  vecarray& operator-=( std::array<T,N> const& rhs )& {
    for (auto& x:*this) {
      x -= rhs[ std::addressof(x)- this->data() ];
    }
    return *this;
  }
  vecarray& operator*=( std::array<T,N> const& rhs )& {
    for (auto& x:*this) {
      x *= rhs[ std::addressof(x)- this->data() ];
    }
    return *this;
  }
  vecarray& operator/=( std::array<T,N> const& rhs )& {
    for (auto& x:*this) {
      x /= rhs[ std::addressof(x)- this->data() ];
    }
    return *this;
  }

  friend vecarray operator+( vecarray lhs, std::array<T, N> const& rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend vecarray operator-( vecarray lhs, std::array<T, N> const& rhs ) {
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend vecarray operator*( vecarray lhs, std::array<T, N> const& rhs ) {
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend vecarray operator/( vecarray lhs, std::array<T, N> const& rhs ) {
    lhs /= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
};
```

this has a whole myriad of improvements over your solution.  Among them, none of the operators are templates, which generates really annoying errors.

Comment: I was not aware of the ADL issue. A question that remains for me regarding your solution is the consequence of the absence of a virtual destructor in `std::array`. Is it correct that as long as `vecarray` does not contain any member variables, your approach is safe in the unlikely case that `vecarray` is accessed by a base pointer to `std::array`?

Comment: @esakaen It is safe so long as nobody deletes a `std::array` on the heap via a raw pointer to it.  Putting a raw `std::array` on the heap is something I have done exactly zero times in my entire life.  I don't think I've even used a typed pointer to a `std::array` in my entire life (just references sometimes).  Very few `std` types are suitable for heap allocation (I mean, heap allocating a `std::vector` just seems strange).  And when you do, use a smart pointer.  It is true that a `unique_ptr<std::array<int, 10>>` will do the wrong thing, but again, why would you use that?